# JPA - select Query increments version column

Tags: jpa

Everytime I'm calling a query (just a select as you can see) my version column gets incremented by one. Has anyone got any idea how that's possible?

I've simulated the query as simple as possible (and that's also how I'm testing it right now).

The query:

```
String queryString = "SELECT pr FROM PaymentRequest pr where pr.status = 'PO_ERROR'";
TypedQuery<PaymentRequest> query = em.createQuery(queryString, PaymentRequest.class);
return query.getResultList();
```

this method gets executed in a new transaction (TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)

JPA version: 2.0

Comment: so perhaps mention what is your JPA implementation (cos mine doesnt increment anything with a SELECT query), and mention the log entries. Clearly a SELECT cannot update anything (barring a trigger in the datastore?)

Comment: @NeilStockton question updated. There are no triggers in the DB.

Comment: @GregD Please provide more details on the JPA Implemetation & Configuration that you are using.

Comment: the JPA implementation? By "log entries" I mean what SQL is executed (which will be printed in the log).

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem.  My entity has @Embeddable properties.  The entity/embeddable gets updated via JSF setters in gui (apply request values phase).  I was getting javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException on the embedded object/property itself.  This was the case when all of the properties of the embedded object were null and therefor the embedded object itself was null after the object got loaded by the entitymanager (hibernate jpa 2).

To fix the PropertyNotFoundException I added a @PostLoad method on my entity to do a new MyEmbbedableObject() if the embeddable was null.  This caused Hibernate to mark the embeddable as dirty which caused an update, which of course caused the version column to increase when the transaction in which the query was executed was being committed.  I removed the PostLoad to instantiate the null embeddables.  That fixed the problem of the "version" increase during a query.
Of course now updating the entity/embeddable via the gui is broken again :-)

Comment: What about creating the embeddable lazy in your getter? That way it is created when JSF accesses the (than detached) bean.

Answer (score 0):

If you use EclipseLink, you can set eclipselink.read-only to retrieve results and avoid to increment version:

```
query.setHint(QueryHints.READ_ONLY, HintValues.TRUE);
```